# Create strings with all possible combinations that include dot between char

Tags: vb.net, string

I have the following string:

```
Dim Str As String = "XYZ"
```

My goal is to achieve every possible string that include dots.
It should take care of:

1. Dot should be between Chars

2. The char order cant be change, its just need to insert some dot between chars.

For example:

```
X.YZ
XY.Z
X.Y.Z
```

- The original string contains up to 50 characters.

Where should I start?

Comment: `Where should I start` with some code showing what you have tried.  See [Ask]

Comment: You should start by questioning your requirements....because that doesn't make much sense at first glance. Or, if it's homework or a coding challenge - start with Google. :)

Answer (score 1):

This might help you get started:

Imagine that a dot = 1 and no dot = 0.
For example U.VX.YZ = U1V0X1Y0Z
Now remove all the letters and you get some binary : 1010
This suggests you can go from 0000 to 1111 in dots (This is hard to explain)
Try doing this process in reverse to get all answers.

For example:

```
String = "XYZ"
00 = XYZ
01 = XY.Z
10 = X.YZ
11 = X.Y.Z
```

Comment: Nice lateral thinking answer!

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand exactly. That is what i do so far:
*And no, it's not homework.`Dim Str As String = "XYZhhfhfghfgjkhh"
        Dim ListStr As New List(Of String)


        For i = 1 To Str.Length * 2 - 2 Step 2
            Str = Str.Insert(i, ".")

        Next
        For i = 0 To Str.Length - 1
            If Replace(Str, ".", "", 1, i).Contains(".") = False Then Exit For
            ListStr.Add(Replace(Str, ".", "", 1, i))
        Next
        Str = Replace(Str, ".", "")

        For i = 0 To ListStr.Count - 1
            Console.WriteLine(ListStr(i))
        Next `

Comment: @DaniLacsi That code is kind of hard to understand btw ^^. You should update your question instead so that it gets formatted properly.